# If iPhone will display Caller ID of person calling you by default

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone a few generations back (with AT&T) and it seems that every number that calls me it only shows the phone number and location, rather than the Caller ID and phone number pair. (Except for numbers that I have in my contacts, in which case it only displays the contact name, no number or location). I'm wondering if this is the default behavior of the iPhone, or what is going on. How do I make it so the Caller ID shows on my phone for whoever is calling me. And what is the default behavior of the major current iPhones in terms of this, that is, if they display Caller ID by default, or display Phone + Location by default, or if it depends on the provider and your account settings at places like AT&T and Verizon.

Comment: it depends on the provider

Comment: I'm on AT&T in Austin TX and that is what happens with my phone

Comment: I have Verizon, so I'm only guessing, but I'm assuming that for some reason the number isn't matching exactly. Try adding a number from your "Recent" numbers to your contacts and see if it works when they call you back. It definitely doesn't seem like something that should happen, but cell phone companies are terrible, so who knows.